# w3af_gui execution: gtk package requirements

Tags: gtk

I want to start ./w3af_gui, but when I execute the command, I receive this error from the terminal:

*The GTK package requirements are not met, please make sure your system meets these requirements:
    - PyGTK >= 2.12
    - GTK >= 2.12*

How can I resolve this problem? My os is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 only ships with GTK+ 3.10. You'll either need to a) find a PPA that provides GTK+ 3.12, b) upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, which provides GTK+ 3.12, or c) downgrade w3af isn't that provided by the system already?).

Comment: but it says 2.12 not 3.12

Comment: Ah, my mistake; sorry. I assume PyGTK is installed, correct?

Comment: I suppose. But if I open python2.7 and I write import pygtk, it returns me an error